# How can I increment a variable to a csv using python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi I just started using python and raspberry pi.
I've got a code that increments four variables depending on which button I press.
These answers go to a csv file which will show me at what time the button was pressed and how many times since the beginning of the program.
The problem here is that the csv file only shows me if I press the button so : 1, 0 , 0 ,0 not 0+n

Can someone please tell me why? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import pygame.mixer
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import time
import csv

from pygame.mixer import Sound
from time import sleep
from datetime import date


with open("Csv_Test.csv", "a") as csv_file:
    csv_app = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_app.writerow(["Hour", "RealyGood", "Good", "bad", "RealyBad"])


    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(37,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
    print("HelloWorld")

    hour = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    print(hour)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    drum = Sound("samples/drum_tom_mid_hard.wav")
    while True:
        heure = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        buttonRealyHappy = GPIO.input(37)   
        buttonHappy = GPIO.input(35)
        buttonbad = GPIO.input(33)
        buttonRealyBad = GPIO.input(31)
        printcsv = 0
        realyHappy =0
        happy =0
        bad = 0 
        realyBad = 0
        if buttonRealyHappy == 0:
            realyHappy += 1
            print("RealyHappy")
            drum.play()
            printcsv = 1
        if buttonHappy == 0:
            happy += 1
            print("Happy")
            drum.play()
            printcsv = 1
        if buttonBad == 0:
            bad += 1
            print("bad")
            drum.play()
            printcsv = 1
        if boutonRealyBad == 0:
            realyBad += 1
            print("Realybad")
            drum.play()
            printcsv = 1

        if (printcsv >  0):
            csv_app.writerow([happy, semi, mal, bad])
            printcsv = 0
            time.sleep(5)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```